# Returning Value from Future functions to onPressed method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use value returned by `Future` method and depending on that I want push new routes into the navigator.

I am new with flutter so I don't know how to get values from `Future` functions. I have tried something like -

```
final value = await signInWithGoogle();
```

Future Function Code -

```
    try {
        final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount
            .authentication;

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );

        final AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final FirebaseUser user = result.user;

        assert(!user.isAnonymous);
        assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

        final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
        assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

        if(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){

          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GetInfo()));
        }
        else {
          name = user.displayName;
          email = user.email;
          imageUrl = user.photoUrl;

          return 1;
        }
      }
      catch(e){
        print(e.message);
        return -1;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
// 1
// FirebaseAuthUtils

class FirebaseAuthUtils {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

     Future<User> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    User user;
    FirebaseUser firebaseuser;
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    try {
      firebaseuser = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      assert(!firebaseuser.isAnonymous);
      assert(await firebaseuser.getIdToken() != null);

      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      assert(firebaseuser.uid == currentUser.uid);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      UtilsImporter().commanUtils.showToast(e.message, context);
    }
    if (firebaseuser != null) {
      user = new User(firebaseuser.displayName, firebaseuser.email, firebaseuser.photoUrl);
    }

    print('===Google Login: ' + user._fullname);
    return user;
  }
}

// 2
// User Model

class User {
  String _fullname;
  String _emailAddress;
  String _profilPic;

  User(this._fullname, this._emailAddress, this._profilPic);

  String get name => _fullname;

  set name(String value) {
    _fullname = value;
  }

  String get emailaddress => _emailAddress;

  set image(String value) {
    _emailAddress = value;
  }

  String get profilepic => _profilPic;

  set profilepic(String value) {
    _profilPic = value;
  }
}

// 3
// Home Page

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {

  FirebaseAuthUtils firebaseAuthUtils = new FirebaseAuthUtils();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //getting screen size
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var user = firebaseAuthUtils.signInWithGoogle;
    print("User : $user");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
  int _value; 

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    int newValue = await signInWithGoogle();
    setState(() {
      _value = newValue;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23985248)